# Как написать функцию, чтобы можно было писать qDebug() << "hello";

Tags: c++, qt

Я не пойму как можно определить функцию, чтобы можно было писать такое:

```
qDebug() << "hello world";
```

В данном примере надо как-то определить функцию `qDebug()`, но как? Если можно, то ответ кодом напишите.

Comment: Так писать не надо, совсем :)  Чего конкретно хочется?

Comment: В qtcreator можно написать qDebug() << "и вывести отладочные сообщения";

Comment: Результат функции `qDebug()` должен позволять применять к нему оператор `<<`. Это все, что нужно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такая функция возвращает объект, к которому применим `operator<<`. Простейшим способом написать аналог будет такой:

```
std::ostream& debug()
{
    return std::cout;
}
```

И это можно использовать как у Вас в примере:

```
debug() << "Hello!";
```

`qDebug()` может быть реализована схожим образом (но реально это макрос, который несколько по-другому реализован), просто возвращать ссылку на объект [`QDebug`](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdebug.html), а не `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 4):

Помимо уже сказанного про применимость `operator<<` к результату `qDebug()`, у класса `QDebug` (возвращаемый из макроса `qDebug`) есть ещё одна особенность, заключающаяся в автоматическом переводе курсора вывода на новую строку, т.е. нет явной необходимости добавлять `'\n'` в конце. С одной стороны это удобно, с другой - несколько раздражает. А реализовано это через обычный деструктор класса, который вызывается при уничтожении объекта `QDebug`, который создаётся каждым новым вызовом `qDebug()`. [Вариант](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B7JZETnc60028ReS) реализации:

```
#include <iostream>

struct D {
    ~D() { std::cout << "\n"; }

    template <typename T>
    D& operator<< (const T& t) 
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
        return *this;
    }    
};

D deb() { return D(); }

int main()
{
    deb() << 42 << "string" << 100.5;
}
```