# Стандартный вывод, автоматический flush

Tags: c++, вывод, flush

Можно ли перевести поток `std::cout` в такой режим, чтобы после каждого вывода автоматически делался `std::cout << std::flush` ?

Варианты решения:

1. Писать `std::flush` явно после каждого вывода
2. Написать обёртку вокруг `std::cout`, перегрузить у неё оператор сдвига, и флушить там.

Но наверняка есть какой-то штатный способ это сделать, нагуглить не удалось, не смог подобрать запрос, чтобы гугл понял, что я хочу. Может кто-нибудь знает, как это сделать?

Comment: После каждого оператора `<<`? А зачем? Где пример вывода?

Comment: Да, после каждого. Мне кажется, данный вопрос не требует никакого примера, так как он не зависит от того, что именно мы собираемся выводить.

Comment: я думаю можно сделать перегрузку внутри своего оператора и сделать flush там. Вот относительно полезная статья если совсем нет представления как это делать ( https://ravesli.com/urok-133-peregruzka-operatorov-vvoda-i-vyvoda/ )

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев , это хороший способ, но его я упомянул как вариант решения в самом вопросе :) , мне хочется найти именно стандартный способ, скорее всего в iomanip есть какой-то манипулятор, который переведёт поток в нужный режим...

Comment: Использовать cerr :) Или endl. Вопрос только - а зачем? что вы хотите - понятно, но зачем?

Comment: Флашить после каждого вывода может быть расточительно. Если достаточно флашить после цепочки вызовов, то можно сделать это в деструкторе. Пример реализации [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905958/176217).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте [`std::unitbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf)

```
 std::cout << std::unitbuf;
```